VBA : Print CSV file as XLSX
I am trying to print a CSV file to look like a XLSX file. What I mean by that is that when I currently print I see :
Current CSV

and what I would like is:
Desired CSV

I already have 2 scripts:
Outlook Session:
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objMail As Object ' Utilisation de Object pour capturer tout type d'élément
    Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim objAttachment As Outlook.attachment
    Dim entryID As String
    Dim entryIDs() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim tempFolder As String
    Dim filePath As String
    
    ' Dossier temporaire pour enregistrer les fichiers
    tempFolder = "C:\temp\"
    
    ' Assurez-vous que le dossier existe
    If Dir(tempFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir tempFolder
    End If
    
    ' Obtenir le Namespace d'Outlook
    Set objNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    ' Diviser la chaîne EntryIDCollection en cas de réception de plusieurs emails
    entryIDs = Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
    
    ' Boucle sur chaque email reçu
    For i = LBound(entryIDs) To UBound(entryIDs)
        entryID = entryIDs(i)
        
        On Error Resume Next
        ' Essayer de récupérer l'élément comme MailItem
        Set objMail = objNamespace.GetItemFromID(entryID)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        ' Vérifier si l'objet a été récupéré correctement
        If Not objMail Is Nothing Then
            ' Vérifier si c'est bien un MailItem
            If TypeOf objMail Is Outlook.mailItem Then
                ' Vérifier si l'objet du mail contient le texte désiré (utilisation de InStr pour plus de flexibilité)
                If InStr(1, Trim(LCase(objMail.Subject)), "People on site", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    
                    ' Obtenir les pièces jointes
                    Set objAttachments = objMail.Attachments
                    
                    ' Boucle à travers les pièces jointes
                    For Each objAttachment In objAttachments
                        ' Vérifier si la pièce jointe est un CSV
                        If LCase(Right(objAttachment.FileName, 3)) = "csv" Then
                            ' Chemin du fichier temporaire
                            filePath = tempFolder & objAttachment.FileName
                            
                            ' Enregistrer la pièce jointe
                            objAttachment.SaveAsFile filePath
                            
                            ' Appel à la fonction d'impression (assure-toi que cette fonction est définie)
                            PrintCSVOnMultiplePrinters filePath
                            
                            ' Supprimer le fichier après impression
                            Kill filePath
                        End If
                    Next objAttachment
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print "Erreur : Impossible de récupérer l'élément avec ID " & entryID
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Libération des objets
    Set objNamespace = Nothing
    Set objMail = Nothing
    Set objAttachments = Nothing
End Sub

Module1 :
Declare PtrSafe Function SetDefaultPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" Alias "SetDefaultPrinterA" (ByVal printerName As String) As Long


Sub PrintCSVOnMultiplePrinters(filePath As String)
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlBook As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Object
    Dim currentPrinter As String

    ' Créer une instance de l'application Excel
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    ' Ouvrir le fichier CSV
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath, False, True)
    
    ' Sélectionner la feuille active
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets(1)
    
    ' Sauvegarder l'imprimante par défaut actuelle
    currentPrinter = xlApp.ActivePrinter
    
    ' Imprimer sur la première imprimante (PEY01) en définissant l'imprimante par défaut
    Call SetDefaultPrinter("\\PRINTSRV01\PEY01")
    xlSheet.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    
    ' Imprimer sur la deuxième imprimante (PEY05) en définissant l'imprimante par défaut
    Call SetDefaultPrinter("\\PRINTSRV01\PEY05")
    xlSheet.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    
    ' Restaurer l'imprimante par défaut précédente
    Call SetDefaultPrinter(currentPrinter)
    
    ' Fermer le fichier sans sauvegarder
    xlBook.Close False
    xlApp.Quit
    
    ' Libérer la mémoire
    Set xlSheet = Nothing
    Set xlBook = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub

As you can see, there's 1 script that switches printers and the other that detects the incoming mail containing the CSV and prints it.

Your file is not a "real" CSV (because it has ; and not , as the delimiter). If you record a macro while stepping through Data tab >> Get data >> From Text/CSV it will show you what you need.

Use a tab separated file rather than , or ;.

It should be noted that the delimiter in non-US locales typically is ; since decimal numbers are using ,.   Excel exports respects the locale setting of Windows, which can be frustrating at times.

Do you need it fully scripted ? If you wish to do some of it manually, you can use use copy to clipboard of your excel data, then paste into something like online Ascii table.   If you wish to go more fancy like right-align numbers etc, it's simple to write your own scripts. Copy from Excel is tab-based.

I can't , instead of ; because it's a generated file from a MSQL database.
